# Flutter - ListView.builder renders widgets but not scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my ListView.builder inside Expanded widget which render widgets correctly on the screen but I cannot scroll the widgets rendered by it.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPostsForUid(),
        builder: (_, snap) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snap.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                if (snap.data[index]['post_type'] == 'real_estate') {
                  return realEstate(snap, index);
                }
                else if (snap.data[index]['post_type'] == 'video_sharing') {
                  return videoSharing(snap, index);
                }
                else {
                  return Text('');
                }

              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

This renders widgets but there is no overflow but its not Scrollable. Using `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics`, `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`, `ScrollPhysics` in physics doesn't work either. Also tring shrinkWrap as `false` returns no widgets whatsoever.
[image]

Comment: Why you are using an `Expanded` widget as child of a container

Comment: I do not know how `Expanded` widget will work without a `Flex` widget. Try restarting your app first. Can you show us your parent widget of of provided snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The list view thinks it’s bigger, because your container has no fixed height. Try setting the height of the container to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` and the list view will know its bounds.

Answer (score 1):

it will not scroll while it's shrinkWrap is true.

try this:

```
ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemExtent: 'sizeOfeachElement (ex:100)'
```

and **remove** `Expanded`